# White circle in notification Samsung s22 ultra, android 13. (Flutter, awesome_notifications)

Tags: android, flutter, awesome-notifications

After the update to android 13, the background color for notifications is not working, the color is always white.

```
await AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
      content: NotificationContent(
        id: 100,
        channelKey: 'scheduled_channel',
        title: 'Hello',
        body: 'This is a sample notification.',
        notificationLayout: NotificationLayout.Default,
        icon: icon,
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
    );
```

This happens only in this version and this device. Android 13 in the emulator works.

There are some posts on other forums where people talk about some apps modifying the default theme, but this is not the case.

https://www.reddit.com/r/GalaxyS22/comments/yczni0/anyone_else_getting_blank_icons_for_notifications/

https://www.reddit.com/r/GalaxyS21/comments/yrgabv/notification_bug_after_oneui_update_all/

[image]

Comment: Is your icon a white image over a transparent background? That's how Android 13 requires notification icons to be now.